# Designing DAO on Ruby

Tags: ruby, data-access-layer, dao

I am just wandering is there is any reference how to design DAO (data access object) with multiple connection to different data source, in the right way. I need to build one on Ruby. In short, it should be object that provides simplified access to data stored in SQL DB, noSQL DB, etc. The methods should be write data to different data source and retrieve data from different data source, of course access to data source should be managed by priority, for example, noSQL much faster that SQL, so the data should be read from noSQL first.

I am pretty sure there are should be few examples, please point them out.

Comment: [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) can be configured to access multiple repositories, however this seems to be poorly documented. I doubt that there are good examples to accomplish what you need, you probably need to write your own solution. You also need to think about synchronization issues between your data sources. This doesn't sound trivial to me, rather to the contrary.

Comment: @Niklas thanks, at least this is something to start with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try datamapper: http://datamapper.org/